# How to get absolute URLs from HTML of a webpage

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, jsoup, web-crawler

Here is an instance. If you go to the source code (Ctrl + U) of http://superior.edu.pk you will see that there is no Base URL and/or http-equi etc. When you will scroll down to check images it will show different URL to complete relative path and when you will check HTML urls (e.g. search AdmissionSchedule.aspx) you will see different URL resolving relative path. My question is: how can i get those relative URLs as absolute URLs? I've tried jsoup abd:hre and element.absUrl("href"); both give me empty string. Setting document.setBaseUri("http://www.example.com"); also not working as there are two different URLs used as base URL, say.

Any help will be appreciating for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you say there are two base URLS? All relative links are pointing to `http://superior.edu.pk/presentation/user/` (as could not be otherwise!).

Try the following code:

```
    //If you use an URL you haven't to especify base URL
    Document doc=Jsoup.connect("http://superior.edu.pk/presentation/user/Default.aspx").get();
    //If you use a file or a String you have. Base URL is http://superior.edu.pk/presentation/user/ of course  
    //Document doc = Jsoup.parse(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("page.htm"), "utf-8", "http://superior.edu.pk/presentation/user/");

    //Only as an example. You can fetch any anchor as wou wish.
    Elements links = doc.select("div.footerMaterial > a");
    for (Element link : links){
        String attr = link.absUrl("href");
        System.out.println(attr);
    }
```

You will see all the absolute URLs correctly. The ones obtained from a relative link pointing to superior.edu.pk and the absolute ones pointing to their respectives domains (www.digitallibrary.edu.pk and www.google.com)

(Edit)

You can also test this code:

```
    Element link = doc.select(".logo > a:nth-child(1) > img:nth-child(1)").first();
    String attr = link.absUrl("src");
    System.out.println(attr);
```

will give you:

```
http://superior.edu.pk/images/logo.jpg
```

Which is correct!

the explanation is that the relative url is `../../images/logo.jpg` which is `http://superior.edu.pk/presentation/user/../../images/logo.jpg` which resolves as `http://superior.edu.pk/images/logo.jpg`.

A page can have only a base url!

Comment: e.g. if you check "../../images/logo.jpg" it will resolve to http://www.superior.edu.pk/images/logo.jpg and i cannot see "/presentation/user/" in this URL. That is why i said relative URLs are resolving with 2 base URLs.

Comment: well.. ../../images/logo.jpg is relative to superior.edu.pk/presentation/user/ also!! check it: http://superior.edu.pk/presentation/user/../../images/logo.jpg